# Flutter Error: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm new in Flutter. I'm trying to develop the banking app project for IOS or Android. I don't understand that what this error means. I don't see anything to make change on code. And, When I compiler, I get this error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty, state: _HomeScreenState#e34f3):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  HomeScreen file:///Users/berfin/VSCodeProjects/bankingapp/lib/main.dart:14:13

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      operation.<anonymous closure> (package:bankingapp/models/operation.dart:12:51)
#1      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:412:31)
#2      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:341:26)
#3      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:188:27)
#4      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
#5      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:50:28)
#6      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:212:44)
#7      operation (package:bankingapp/models/operation.dart:14:6)
#8      operation (package:bankingapp/models/operation.dart)
#9      _HomeScreenState.build (package:bankingapp/screens/homescreen.dart:189:49)
#10     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#12     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
#13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
#14     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4553:5)
#15     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4737:11)
#16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4548:5)
...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
#40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
#41     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6221:36)
#42     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6232:32)
...     Normal element mounting (170 frames)
#212    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
#213    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6221:36)
#214    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6232:32)
...     Normal element mounting (345 frames)
#559    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
#560    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3363:18)
#561    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1189:16)
#562    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1159:5)
#563    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1104:18)
#564    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2535:19)
#565    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree
(package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1103:13)
#566    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:937:7)
#567    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:917:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

homescreen.dart

```
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 16, bottom: 13, top: 29, right: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Operation",
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              color: kBlackColor),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: map<Widget>(operation, (index, selected) {
                            return Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              height: 9,
                              width: 9,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: current == index
                                      ? kBlueColor
                                      : kTwentyBlueColor),
                            );
                          }),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 123,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: operation.length,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                current = index;
                              });
                            },
                            child: OperationCard(
                                operation: operation[index].name,
                                selectedItem: operation[index].selectedItem,
                                unselectedItem: operation[index].unselectedItem,
                                isSelected: current == index,
                                context: this),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
```

operation.dart (model)

```
class OperationModel {
  String name;
  String selectedItem;
  String unselectedItem;

  OperationModel(this.name, this.selectedItem, this.unselectedItem);
}

List<OperationModel> operation = operationData
    .map(
      (item) => OperationModel(
          item['name'], item['selectedItem'], item['unselectedItem']),  // ERROR IS HERE
    )
    .toList();

List<Map<String, dynamic>> operationData = [
  {
    "name": "Money\nTransfer",
    "selectedItem": "assets/svg/money_transfer_white.svg",
    "unselectedItem": "assets/svg/money_transfer_blue.svg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bank\nWithdraw",
    "selectedItem": "assets/svg/bank_withdraw_white.svg",
    "unselectedIcon": "assets/svg/bank_withdraw_blue.svg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Insight\nTracking",
    "selectedItem": "assets/svg/insight_tracking_white.svg",
    "unselectedItem": "assets/svg/insight_tracking_blue.svg"
  },
];
```

OperationCard (class)

```
class OperationCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String operation;
  final String selectedItem;
  final String unselectedItem;
  final bool isSelected;
  _HomeScreenState context;

  OperationCard(
      {required this.operation,
      required this.selectedItem,
      required this.unselectedItem,
      required this.isSelected,
      required this.context});
  @override
  _OperationCardState createState() => _OperationCardState();
}

class _OperationCardState extends State<OperationCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
      width: 123,
      height: 123,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: kTenBlackColor,
                blurRadius: 10,
                spreadRadius: 5,
                offset: Offset(8.0, 8.0))
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          color: widget.isSelected ? kBlueColor : kWhiteColor),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SvgPicture.asset(
              widget.isSelected ? widget.selectedItem : widget.unselectedItem),
          SizedBox(
            height: 9,
          ),
          Text(
            widget.operation,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: widget.isSelected ? kBlueColor : kWhiteColor),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This error should fixed shortly, because I can't continue in this project. PLEASE HELP ME!! :):):):)

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety read this article

Comment: can you mention at which line of code you are getting the error? that will be heloful

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm editing the question. (error is inside the operation.dart)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
OperationModel(
      item['name']??"", item['selectedItem']?? "", item['unselectedItem']??""),
```

the error is that you are storing null in String, make sure null is not passed, that's why I have added ?? , this operator check if the variable is null, if yes, then it will pass empty string in place "".

Comment: I did it, but I get new error about SVG picture. I don't see any svg picture in IOS simulator